# Send Twitter using Twitter SDK in IOS5

Tags: exc-bad-access

Hell everyone,

I am trying to use Twitter framework to post a twitter message in my application on IOS5, how every when I run my application, which shows Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the line of code:    iOS5twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) ;

Here the block of Twitter code:

//code block

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *iOS5twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

[iOS5twitter addImage:self.item.image];    
[iOS5twitter addURL:self.item.URL];

//if I comment out the following block of code, it works.
iOS5twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) 
{
    [self.currentTopViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    switch (result) {

        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            [self sendDidFinish];
            break;

        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            [self sendDidCancel];                

        default:
            break;
    }
};   
//the above code can be commented out, the it works.

[self.currentTopViewController presentViewController:iOS5twitter animated:YES completion:nil];
[iOS5twitter release];
```

//code block end

If I comment out the block of the following code, it works and message can be posted in Twitter, but the only issue is the application can't prompt the dialog if the message is posted successfully or not.

```
//if I comment out the following block of code, it works.
```

/* iOS5twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) 
    {
        [self.currentTopViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

```
    switch (result) {

        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            [self sendDidFinish];
            break;

        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            [self sendDidCancel];                

        default:
            break;
    }
};
```

*/
    //the above code can be commented out, the it works.

Could anyone help me to figure out how can I fix the EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue and enable to prompt the end user when message is posted successfully or not?

Thanks in advance!

---

Finally the above code works on real device(iphone 4s ios5.1) without commenting the block code, it's so strange, so if you also got the above issue one simulator, I would like to suggest you try it on real device.

The question to Apple is why we get different result between simulator and real device, which will make developer crazy? ...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but I don't think I have enough points to be able to post a comment.

I am getting the same behavior in the iPhone Simulator with SDK 5.1 on my Mac.  I would recommend writing a rdar:// on this.

http://bugreport.apple.com